# Stream array of audio Javascript Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

How can I play an array buffer as audio in Chrome Packaged App?
I'm getting the array through sockets, and I need to keep playing it until I got the 'end' command.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html

The MediaSource API was designed specifically for that. There is a nice working demo at http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this new API as well:

**Web Audio API**

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/